# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Monitor Gnome Crashes

Tags: gnome, xorg, 18.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Inspiron 13 ( Tried an upgrade from 16.04, didn't succeed, then reinstalled without data loss )

Here is what happens -

```
Switch on / Login to Gnome ( x11 ) with an external monitor attached > gnome becomes unresponsive
```

( Some time extensions are working fine since i can system monitor graphs scrolling, but mouse clicks and keyboard wont work )

Potential Culprits -

- Multi monitor add on
- Gnome itself

The only way that works -

```
Login without external monitor attached > disable multi monitor add on > attach external monitor > enable add on
```

this made me think the add on is at fault. But here is another scenario in which Gnome hangs -

```
Add on is disabled, fresh boot > login with external monitor attached > gnome unresponsive
```

Has anyone else faced this? What could be the potential issue / potential debugging steps?

No graphics card in picture

Its literally frustrating!

Comment: I have a similar problem, though the workaround doesn't work.

Comment: I have a similar problem, though the workaround doesn't work.  If I have the second monitor plugged in, both screens display the screen background for the greeter, but once I'm logged in, both screens keep resetting until I unplug the second screen.  If I log in with only the laptop screen, when I plug in the second monitor (either via VGA or HDMI), the screens go blank.  The mouse pointer appears on the laptop screen (keeps repositioning).  I am able to use <ctrl><alt>F3 and log in to a text screen (appears on both monitors). HP G70T-200 17" laptop.